# Elastic Search - Reverse match query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Currently I wrote a query against an elastic server to remove all documents with an old "BatchVersion".  After thinking about it, to be safe, I want all records delete that don't equal the current "BatchVersion".   Here is my current code

```
            _client.DeleteByQuery<Data.ElasticSearch.Employee>(s => s
            .Index(indexName)
            .Size(1000)
            .Query(q => q.
                  Bool(b => b.
                      MustNot(mn => mn.
                            Match(m => m.Field("BatchVersion").
                                  Query([newVersionId]))))));
```

When the code is run, no records are deleted.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a mapping for BatchVersion field and sample values

Answer (score 0):

I had to use Default_Field for it to work.  I used kibana to figure it out.

```
            _client.DeleteByQuery<Employee>(s => s
            .Index(indexName)
            .Size(1000)
            .Query(q => q.
                Bool(b => b.
                    MustNot(mn => mn.
                        QueryString(qs => qs.DefaultField("batchVersion").Query(newVersionId.ToString()))))));
```